# Flask can't read the /etc/environment

Tags: python, linux, flask

I am getting a problem with the credentials of gmail in flask.

If I use this:

```
MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
```

I will get this error:

**SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.)**

If I set the username and password in the py file, all works great.

---

In /etc/environment I have:

```
export MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@gmail.com
export MAIL_PASSWORD=password
```

So, flask can't read the `/etc/environment`.

Any idea?

Comment: As side note: works with .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

/etc/environment [doesn't do what you think](https://superuser.com/questions/664169/what-is-the-difference-betwen-etc-environment-and-etc-profile). Even if it did, this seem like a very strange way to store configuration, and very insecure (store a password in a globally-readable file?)

This should really be in your app's configuration file. Else, /etc/profile would do what you want.

Comment: In docs, they recommend store the pass in the linux system. The problem is that when I export the variables, i can't reboot the system. I need to store the mail and pass persistently. Any problem if I set the variables in bashrc?

Comment: [The documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#configuring-from-files) advises you to use a configuration file, optionally allowing a (single) environment variable to specify an alternate location of that file. This would allow you to do `CONFIG_FILE=test_config.py ./myapp.py` (e.g. for testing purposes).

Comment: I suppose that pointing to a config file means I should set ownership and permissions to that file only for the apps that use it. So to give my email to several reporting apps, I would have to put them in a group and have it own the config file?...   I am also trying to get secrets to work through a keychain, but am stuck: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/690295/error-secret-tool-cannot-create-an-item-in-a-locked-collection

Comment: Just have multiple files